# Can't pass Vue data into Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can't seem to pass Vue data into Vue component from an inline template.

I'm getting this error instead:

```
vue.min.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

Below is my example code that I'm using:

```js
Vue.component('data-item', {
  props: ['food'],
  template:"<li>{{food}}</li>"
})


var content = new Vue({
  el: '#content',
  data: {
    value: 'hello value!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <!-- this works
  <ol>
    <li>{{value}}</li>
  </ol>
  -->
  
  <!-- passing data from vue instance to component doesn't work -->
  <ol>
    <data-item  v-bind:food="value" inline-template></data-item>
  </ol>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need `inline-template` if you have setted `template: "<li>{{food}}</li>"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to use `inline-template` without including an inline template.   `inline-template` replaces the `template` of the component with whatever is inside its DOM node; you're getting `undefined` because it's empty.

If you want to use inline-template:

```js
Vue.component('data-item', {
  props: ['food'],
  template: "<li>This will be ignored in favor of the inline-template: {{food}}</li>"
})

var content = new Vue({
  el: '#content',
  data: {
    value: 'hello value!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <ol>
    <data-item v-bind:food="value" inline-template>
      <li>I am the inline template: {{food}}</li>
    </data-item>
  </ol>
</div>
```

If you want to use `data-item`'s 'template' instead, just don't include `inline-template` on the element:

```js
Vue.component('data-item', {
  props: ['food'],
  template:"<li>I am the component template: {{food}}</li>"
})

var content = new Vue({
  el: '#content',
  data: {
    value: 'hello value!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <ol>
    <data-item v-bind:food="value">
      I am the contents of the DOM node, which will be
      replaced by data-item's template.
    </data-item>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `is` attribute

```
   Vue.component('data-item', {
      props: ['food'],
      template:"<li>{{food}}</li>"
    })

    var content = new Vue({
      el: '#content',
      data: {
      value: 'hello value!'
      }
    })


    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
    <div id="content">
      <ol>
        <li is="data-item" v-bind:food="value"></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
```